# Only return rows if sum is greater than a value

Tags: sql, db2, sum

I have built this SQL Query which searches for all policy numbers and returns a sum of all multiple PPOLNO's currency values :

```
SELECT PPOLNO, SUM(PPRMPD) AS SUM 
FROM PFNTLPYMTH 
WHERE SUM(PPRMPD) >= 5000 
  AND  ((PYEAR=2012 AND PMONTH >=3 
  AND PDAY >=27) OR (PYEAR=2013 
  AND PYEAR <=3 AND PDAY<=27))
GROUP BY PPOLNO
```

What I'm looking at doing is only returning them if the SUM >= a specific value.  Is this possible and how?  I tried this:

```
SELECT PPOLNO, SUM(PPRMPD) AS SUM FROM PFNTLPYMTH
WHERE SUM(PPRMPD) >= 5000 AND ((PYEAR=2012 AND PMONTH >=3 AND PDAY >=27) OR (PYEAR=2013 
AND PYEAR <=3 AND PDAY<=27)) GROUP BY PPOLNO
```

But to no avail.  I've also just tried putting in WHERE SUM >= 5000, but again, nothing there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Josh

Comment: You realize your date range is for a year-and-a-day, not just a year, right?  (That, and I'm assuming you've just made a typo for `PYEAR <= 3`).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Whenever you need to do a "WHERE" clause on an aggregate (which `SUM` is), you need to use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT PPOLNO, SUM(PPRMPD) AS SUM FROM PFNTLPYMTH
WHERE ((PYEAR=2012 AND PMONTH >=3 AND PDAY >=27) OR (PYEAR=2013 
AND PYEAR <=3 AND PDAY<=27)) GROUP BY PPOLNO
HAVING SUM(PPRMPD) >= 5000
```

Comment: @derek Kromm , thanks for reminding of Having Clause. While learning PLSQL i never knew the true meaning of using HAVING in an appropriate sql statement, but this clears my doubts 100%; Thanksagain

Answer (score 2):

Predicates in the `Where` clause are applied *before* aggregation,  To apply a predicate (filter) *after* aggregation, use a `Having` clause... try

```
SELECT PPOLNO, SUM(PPRMPD) AS SUM 
FROM PFNTLPYMTH 
WHERE  ((PYEAR=2012 AND PMONTH >=3 
  AND PDAY >=27) OR (PYEAR=2013 
  AND PYEAR <=3 AND PDAY<=27))
GROUP BY PPOLNO
Having SUM(PPRMPD) >= 5000
```

Comment: I need to look more into how filtering works it looks like.  Thank you very much Charles.  Much appreciated!